# Given cbegin(), cend(), why is there no cfront(), cback(), cfind(), ...?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

So, in order to allow code such as

```
auto vect = ...;
auto it = vect.begin(), end = vect.end(); // want const_iterator, getting iterator
```

to pick the right overload of `begin()` and `end()`, even for non-const containers, the more explicit `cbegin()`/`cend()` functions were added.

Why stop there?

Associative containers have a `find()` method with the same problem. Sequence containers have `front()` and `back()`, again with the same problem.

Are these missing explicit const versions omissions, or by design?

Comment: They are overloaded, i.e. `const_reference front() const;` and `reference front();`

Comment: I don't see the need for  a `cfront` function. What is the significant problem that would solve? `cbegin`/`cend` were required fairly often, which is a justification for the working group to introduce that function.

Comment: @Columbo: who's counting how many uses of non-existing functions are in the total of C++ programs? I knew the committee was a circle of wizards, but that they can read the minds of all C++ developers is new to me. Seriously, though, the C++ standard is not a popularity contest. If you add one new mechanism, you should add it everywhere it's useful, not stop half-way, or should you?

Comment: @jrok: So are `const_iterator begin() const` and `iterator begin()`. What's your point?

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz The standard library *is* to some extent  a popularity contest. Functions that are solely syntax sugar are never introduced unless they would constitute an important/idiomatic part of the library.

Comment: Massive member function bloat is not a good thing. Look at `std::string` and its 128 member functions. (Yes, I counted.)

Comment: @T.C. 128 and still missing so many useful things (e.g. `starts_with`)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A wider API has cost, even just to skip over it when looking for the function you want.

```
template<class T>
T const as_const(T&& t) noexcept(noexcept(T(std::declval<T>())) {
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}
template<class T>
T const& as_const(T& t) noexcept {
  return t;
}
```

does most of what you want.  It would even make `cbegin` obsolete.

(modifications done to the code above based off n4380 supplied by @T.C below.  Code differs, because I think n4380 got it slightly wrong in the `T&&` case.)

Comment: @t.c. time travelling plagiarists!

Comment: I like `as_const` :) Let's hope `cbegin()`/`cend()` will then be deprecated quickly, because an inconsistent API has an even higher cost.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `cbegin`/`cend` is to solve a specific problem. Consider this code:

```
std::vector<int> & v = //... v is a non-const reference

// For clarity, I want this iterator to be a const_iterator.
// This works because iterator is implicitly convertible to const_iterator
std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = find(v.begin(),v.end(),42);

// (1) Now I want to use iter in an algorithm
std::find(iter, v.end(), 38); //Error, can not deduce the template parameter for Iter. 

// (2) This works
std::find(iter, const_cast<const std::vector<int> &>(v).end(), 38);

// (3) This is the same as (2).
std::find(iter, v.cend(), 38);
```

The problem is that, due to how template deduction rules work, the compiler can not deduce the template iterator argument in the statement (1), because `Container::iterator` and `Container::const_iterator` are (potentially) two completely unrelated types (even if the former is implicitly convertible in the latter).

The statement (2) is not exactly a beautiful line, that is why we *need* `cend()`.

Now, `front()`, `back()` et similia all return a reference. A non-const reference can always be deduced as const in a templated function, that is:

```
template<class T> void f( const T & l, const T & r);

int main()
{
    int x; vector<int> v;

    //This will works even if the return type of front() is int&.
    f(x, v.front());
 }
```

Since `Container::const_reference` is required by the standard to be equal to `const Container::value_type &`,  `cfront()`/`cback()` do not buy us anything.

---

It is worth mentioning that other containers library (looking at you Qt) are implemented using Copy-On-Write.

This means that calling a const function on such container is potentially much less expensive than calling the equivalent non-const version, simply because the non-const might copy the entire container under the hood.

For this reason the Qt containers have a lot of `constFunction` in their interface, and the user has the freedom to pick the right one.

Comment: I was under the impression that `cbegin()` and `cend()` are for getting the right type in auto variable declarations. And yes, the Qt containers have the detach problem (as does `std::string` in libstdc++).

Comment: `const Container::reference` and `const Container::value_type &` (aka `Container::const_reference`) are very different things.